# .netcore `GLIBC_2.14' not found error on linux (RHEL)

Tags: linux, .net-core

On windows 10, I created a .netCore (3.1.200) console application called helloWorld. Published it using the command:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true
```

Copied over the publish folder to my linux machine (RHELS 6.10). 
Applied the executable permission `chmod +x helloWorld`

When I run the command, `helloWorld`, I am getting this error:

```
 helloWorld: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by helloWorld)
```

How can I resolve that?

Comment: That's exactly why RHEL has its own RIDs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer for anyone else having the same issue.

publish command : `dotnet publish -r rhel.6-x64 --self-contained true`

When you run it on RHEL you will get another error saying "ICU is missing".

To Resolve that : 
Add a new file in your project called **runtimeconfig.template.json**

Add this to the file:

```
{
  "configProperties": {
      "System.Globalization.Invariant": true
    }
  }
```

Now republish and re-run.